# Mask array entries when column index is greater than a certain cutoff that is unique to each row

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to efficiently mask a large array with several hundred thousand rows and ~500 columns wherever column index is greater than `cutoff[i]`,  0 <= `i` < number of rows.

Here is an example:

```
In [2]: x = np.random.randint(0,100,size=24).reshape((6,4)); x
Out[2]:
array([[86, 50, 19, 49],
       [41, 80, 94, 50],
       [36, 58, 66, 50],
       [67, 45, 76, 18],
       [80, 14, 10, 30],
       [25, 90, 44, 38]])

In [3]: cutoff = np.array([10,4,3,2,1,0]); cutoff
Out[3]: array([10,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0])
```

Now I basically want to create a `mask` with `mask[:, cutoff:]=True`, but of course this gives me error. End result that I'm looking for:

```
[[86 50 19 49]
 [41 80 94 50]
 [36 58 66 --]
 [67 45 -- --]
 [80 -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- --]]
```

Is there a faster way to do the following?

```
In [4]: mask = np.zeros_like(x)

In [5]: for row in range(x.shape[0]):
   ...:     mask[row, cutoff[row]:] = 1
   ...:

In [6]: mask
Out[6]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])

In [7]: np.ma.array(x, mask=mask)
Out[7]:
masked_array(data =
 [[86 50 19 49]
 [41 80 94 50]
 [36 58 66 --]
 [67 45 -- --]
 [80 -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- --]],
             mask =
 [[False False False False]
 [False False False False]
 [False False False  True]
 [False False  True  True]
 [False  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

I'm open to using pandas if it's easier or faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use broadcast:

```
cutoff = np.array([10,4,3,2,1,0])
np.arange(4)[None, :] >= cutoff[:, None]
```

Here is the result:

```
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Or use `outer()` method of ufunc:

```
np.less_equal.outer(cutoff, np.arange(4))
```